# Swapping rows in a row echelon

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make a program that computes, given any matrix `A`, its echelon form. Here is my code:

```
function A = myrref(A)

[m,n]=size(A);

for j=1:min(m,n)    
    A(j,:) = A(j,:)/A(j,j);
    for i = j+1:m
        A(i,:)= A(i,:)- A(j,:)*A(i,j);
        if A(i,i) == 0
            row1=A(i,:);
            A(i,:)=A(i+1,:);
            A(i+1,:)=row1;
        end  
    end 
end
```

It seems to work almost fine, but I still have a problem when swapping rows. For instance, when trying to get echelon form of matrix `A=[1 1 1; 2 2 1; 1 2 2]`, I obtain `[1 1 1; 0.5 1 1; 0  0 -1]` which is not what I want. Do I need to add another loop that takes care of the `0.5` in the second row first column?

Comment: Is simply `rref(A)` not what you want?

Comment: yes, but I want to actually write the program to understand loops better.

Comment: you have to finish up the column loop before you can decide if the pivot is zero. So that when you swap there is no nonzero value coming up behind the current index of the loop. The swaps are easier if you just multiply with a permutation matrix instead of row juggling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it is simplier to use `while` loop for `j` because `j` is not necessarily growing on each iteration. The leading coefficient is not necessarily located on the main diagonal; when all the elements below the leading `0` are zeros, the leading coefficient position shifts to the right.

Secondly, the leading coefficient should be checked before `A(j,:)/A(j,j)` (to prevent division by `0`)

Thirdly, the temporary is not needed to swap the rows as `A([i j],:)= A([j i],:)` 
swaps the `i`th and `j`th rows of `A`.

Here is my version of `myrref`:

```
function A = myrref(A)
[m,n]=size(A);
j= 1; % the row index of the leading coefficient position
k= 1; % the column index of the leading coefficient position
while j<m && k<=n
    if A(j,k)==0 % we need to change the row order
        zeroindex= find(A(j+1:end,k)~=0); % find nonzero elements below A(j,k)
        if isempty(zeroindex)
            k= k+1; % there is no such elements; shift to the right
        else
                % swap the rows
            A([j zeroindex(1)+j],:)= A([zeroindex(1)+j j],:);
        end
    else
        A(j,:) = A(j,:)/A(j,k);
        for i= j+1:m
            A(i,:)= A(i,:)- A(j,:)*A(i,k);
        end
        j= j+1; k= k+1;
    end    
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as @percusse said you need to finish the loop also your pivot should only go to `m-1`

Edit: Added an initial pivot based on @AVK's comment

```
function A = myrref(A)
[m,n]=size(A);

for i = 1:m-1
    if A(i,i) == 0
        row1=A(i,:);
        A(i,:)=A(i+1,:);
        A(i+1,:)=row1;
    end
end

for j=1:min(m,n)
    A(j,:) = A(j,:)/A(j,j);
    for i = j+1:m
        A(i,:)= A(i,:)- A(j,:)*A(i,j);
    end

    for i = j+1:m-1
        if A(i,i) == 0
            row1=A(i,:);
            A(i,:)=A(i+1,:);
            A(i+1,:)=row1;
        end
    end
end
```